# Subquery returned more than one value, =, !=, <, <=, >, >=

Tags: mysql, query-builder

Implementing a sub query in a query, that returns the last loan remove of a DVD by using max(dateOut).

The query gives the correct return in the loan table, however when trying to implement as a subquery gives an error, any idea what should be done? The max(dateout) section. When testing error shown below.

```
SELECT 
    DVDTitle.DVDTitle, 
    Loan.LoanNumber, 
    Member.MemberNumber, 
    Member.MemberFirstName, 
    Member.MemberLastName, 
    (SELECT max(DateOut) FROM Loan, DVDCopy GROUP BY DVDCopy.CopyNumber), 
    Loan.DateDue, Loan.DateReturned
FROM 
    DVDCopy 
INNER JOIN 
    Loan 
    ON DVDCopy.CopyNumber = Loan.CopyNumber 
INNER JOIN 
    Member 
    ON Loan.MemberNumber = Member.MemberNumber 
INNER JOIN 
    DVDTitle 
    ON DVDCopy.DVDNumber = DVDTitle.DVDNumber
WHERE  
    (DVDCopy.CopyNumber = @CopyNumber)
```

The error is:

> There was an error executing the query. Please check the syntax of the command and if present, the types and values of the parameters and ensure they are correct. Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <=, >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

The expected result should return the last loan of a specific DVD based on copy number, from the loan table and DVD Copy table in a grid view based on a dropdownlist (here the copy number is selected). Any ideas, thank you.

Comment: To start, I've formatted your query to make it readable and "debuggable". I would recommend you doing this for yourself going forward or you will have a lot of difficulty debugging. Regarding the query, what's going on with your subquery that there is no `ON` in your join? I would also recommend reformatting your query to avoid comma joins and use explicit JOIN syntax everywhere. Comma join syntax is 27 years outdated.

Comment: Thanks for editing - Looks much better! There is no on in my join? there is on within the joins, unless you mean something else. Comma join is default from Query builder in ASP.net, maybe you should give them an email!

Comment: I'd rather just make sure that I write code properly instead of letting an ORM do it improperly. Where is the `ON` clause in this statement? `(SELECT max(DateOut) FROM Loan, DVDCopy GROUP BY DVDCopy.CopyNumber)`

Comment: Where would the ON be placed?

Comment: The subquery uses two tables but there's no join condition: you are missing something in there. Also, where's the column `DateOut` coming from?

Comment: OK, when you run the subquery `SELECT max(DateOut) FROM Loan, DVDCopy GROUP BY DVDCopy.CopyNumber`... how many rows do you get?

Comment: it gets the max date of each copy, 529

Comment: So you get 529 rows, and the error says you can only return 1 from that subquery. Because logically, how would you display 529 rows in a single column?

Comment: That is correct, so what I want it to do is when the dropdownlist is selected for each copy number (e.g. 8) it returns the last loan date of copy 8.

Comment: Well start with getting your subquery to return 1 row instead of 529!

Comment: Using parameter?

Comment: Using a query that returns 1 row instead of 529...

Answer (score 0):

How about moving your sub-query in `SELECT` to `INNER JOIN`:

```
SELECT 
    DVDTitle.DVDTitle, 
    Loan.LoanNumber, 
    Member.MemberNumber, 
    Member.MemberFirstName, 
    Member.MemberLastName, 
    mdo.MaxDateOut, 
    Loan.DateDue, Loan.DateReturned
FROM 
    DVDCopy 
INNER JOIN 
    Loan 
    ON DVDCopy.CopyNumber = Loan.CopyNumber 
INNER JOIN 
    Member 
    ON Loan.MemberNumber = Member.MemberNumber 
INNER JOIN 
    DVDTitle 
    ON DVDCopy.DVDNumber = DVDTitle.DVDNumber
INNER JOIN
(SELECT CopyNumber,max(DateOut) as "MaxDateOut" FROM Loan, DVDCopy GROUP BY DVDCopy.CopyNumber) mdo 
    ON DVDCopy.CopyNumber = mdo.CopyNumber
WHERE  
    (DVDCopy.CopyNumber = @CopyNumber)
```